# Matplotlib streamplot varying color

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I intend to make a streamlines plot with varying color indicating the intensity at different points with a 2D array. u,v representing the wind components at different points.

Code:

```
x = np.linspace(71.679886,100.43091,299) ##longitude
y = np.linspace(10.64794,31.228256,231)  ##latitude
level = [0,5]
for t in level:  ##t is level in output
    U = u[t,:,:]
    V = v[t,:,:]
    f = X[t,:,:]
    SPD = sqrt(u**2+v**2)
    print(SPD)
    pyplot.streamplot(x,y,u,v,density=5,arrowsize=1,integration_direction='forward',color=SPD,cmap="autumn",linewidth=2)
    pyplot.show()
```

The output should look similar to this:
[image]

[Link](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.streamplot) shows that such plots can be made with specifying a 2D array with `color`, but I get the error: `ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4`, if I use a 2D array, `color=SPD`.
Kindly help.

Comment: Maybe this works? Before the loop: `cmap = plt.get_cmap('autumn')`; norm = plt.Normalize(min(level), max(level))`. And then inside the loop: `plt.streamplot(..., color=cmap(norm(SPD)))`,

Comment: @JohanC  I got the error:ValueError: If 'color' is given, it must match the shape of 'Grid(x, y)' . I dont think normalisation should be done for "level", but for SPD. level is specifying the vertical layer to subset for the plot in each loop. So i tried normalising within the loop, but I got another error for that. ValueError: If 'color' is given, it must match the shape of 'Grid(x, y)'